# Is there a website that has close-up pictures of minifigs?

Tags: minifigures, lego-group, set-database

I am looking for pictures of minifigs to use for my profile pictures.

Searching Google turned up lots of results but most have a bunch of minifigs in them which requires extensive Photoshopping. I am just looking for a website with a bunch of pictures of minifigs or maybe a database if there is one!

Comment: presumably you also want public domain or at least royalty-free images?

Comment: Yes. That's what I would like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brickset.com has minifies entries for the majority of sets. here's an example.

http://brickset.com/sets/60120-1

Click on the minifigs tab. Some are on a plain white background, some not.

There's also heaps on BrickLink.com

http://www.bricklink.com/catalogTree.asp?itemType=M